# regex to match any 1+ non-blankspace character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a Regex for matching a single (or greater) non- blank space character (would allow all special characters such as !,' etc...). Would

```
  var filter = /\S+/;
```

be sufficient? This seems to work for 1 or greater.

Would:

```
  var filter = /\S+/{3,};
```

be sufficient for 3 or more of the non-same characters (like "def", "a!c", "dA!!f", but not "some bird"?

Comment: Use anchors: `/^\S{3,}$/`

Comment: ahh... might want an $ at end too